# How to align wrapped text to the center

Tags: html, css

I have an `h1` element which gets wrapped in smaller screens
How can I make the wrapped text align itself to the center using css?

This is what I want

```
welcome To our site, the no. 1 site
        to get all ur books
```

Comment: h1 {text-align: center;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example, the h1 element is this `<h1 class="heading">Welcome To our site, the no. 1 site to get all your books</h1>`, add this to the css: `.heading{text-align:center}`

Comment: Omg Thanks
I thought that text-align works for only first line of the text and therefore I did not even try It.
Thank you buddy

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks, this is actually the first time my submission got accepted as an answer

Comment: @Abhishek It works on all text, for ex: HTML:```<div class="parent"><p id="p1">Text</p><div class="nested-div"><p id="p2">Text No.2</p></div></div>```, CSS: ```.parent{text-align:center;}```, in the code(s) I wrote before, all the Text Elements in the Parent DIV will get centered no matter where it is.

Answer (score 0):

- There is no way to be fit for your style.
- But try to do this way

```
  <span>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">welcome To our site, the no. 1 site</h1>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">to get all ur books</h1>
  </span>
```